# Where should I report printing errors in Xanathar's Guide to Everything?

Tags: dnd-5e, books

I've found a printing error in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* in the Ancestral Guardian Barbarian subclass. The subclass table lists different dice sizes than the feature descriptions.

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to report this. Do I send it to the Sage Advice address or is there another email?

Comment: @AprilRyanLavellan I posted a separate question for this printing error as I'm sure plenty of people will be searching for it. Do you want to leave an answer? https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110423/34885

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While the specific error you mentioned has already been addressed as listed in [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110423/37158), in general if you find a problem with a Wizards of the Coast product you should contact their customer service department. While I know most people tend to dread the thought of contacting a company's customer service, Wizards has nice people who want to help you be a satisfied customer. They can help direct feedback to appropriate people within their organization, or get you replacements if you received a defective product.

At the bottom of pages on their web site is a "Customer Service" link, pointing to http://wizards.custhelp.com/, which has [support articles](https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2303) you can search and also lists several methods by which you can [contact them](https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2305/):

### Send a message on their web site

You can [send a message](https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/ask) with your questions or concerns. This requires setting up a "Wizards account" on their site, which you may or may not already have.

### Phone

You can push numbers into a handy Wand of Telecommunication and actually speak with a human being far away, much like the Message spell but over a much longer range. In North America the number to dial is 800-324-6496, available seven days a week from 9am to 5pm Pacific Time. (They happen to be Wizards of the *West* Coast.) Contact information for other regions of the world is also available [on their support site](https://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2305/).

### Twitter

The [@Wizards_Help](https://twitter.com/Wizards_Help) account is an officially monitored account where Wizards customer support reads and answers questions and comments.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question, which I'm surprised hadn't been asked before.