# Are the dice for the Barbarian Path of Ancestrial Guardians Spirit Shield d8s or d6s?

Tags: dnd-5e

The table in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* has it listed as progressing from 2d8 upwards while the text of the ability progresses in d6s. Which is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The text is correct per [this Crawford Tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/929077825881088000):

> The text of Spirit Shield is correct. The table is incorrect. Thankfully, this error has already been fixed in @DnDBeyond and in the immediate reprint we had to do for the book.